# Check if multiple textboxes are empty PHP if not then execute php

Tags: if-statement, textbox

```
<?
  if ($_POST['username'] == NULL){ //if nothing is entered or only a zero is entered
    echo "Missing a field.";
  }else{
    //rest of code
  }
```

This won't handle multiple textboxes I have 3: username, password, email

Comment: Can you explain your problem more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below `PHP` code

```
<?
if ($_POST['username'] == NULL || 
    $_POST['password'] == NULL || 
    $_POST['email'] == NULL)
{ //if nothing is entered or only a zero is entered
echo "Missing a field.";
}else{
//rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($_POST['memberfullname'])){ 
    header("Location:srgbusinesspartnersmsg.php");
 } else {
    $insert= $con->command($ins);
    header("Location:srgvalidatepartners.php");
}
```

This works for me. if it is empty , redirect a dialog form and else execute the job which is here  an insert statement to be executed

Join us on Missionsoft Programming Institute (mtscertification.com)